# Is there any way to Support UDP Stream in ROKU?

Tags: roku, brightscript

My video file Format is MPEG. I play **HTTP(https://l1uqyex-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/856741/livestreamC/video1.m3u8)** File It's Working Fine. But I Store in **Locally(pkg://images/Video1.ts)** and use **UDP(udp://192.111.1.1@224.1.1.1:8510)** Stream But It's Not Working. Is There Any way to Support UPD Stream on Roku.

Answer (score 0):

Roku supports HTTP streams only. It doesn't support UDP or any other protocols for streaming video content. Check the sdk documentation for streaming specifications, somewhere you will find it for sure.

Comment: I read all the documentation. probably, not possible, but I think I try with roStreamSocket and see if I can assemble the incoming data into something playback. It would still need to be h.264.

Comment: roStreamSocket is to connect to TCP streams not UDP.  If you want to try, try it with roDataGramSocket.

Comment: Is there any way to supply decryption key to player.

Comment: Hi Nikunj, there is no build-in component in roku to handle epg. Actually epg is custom component. If you want to use it in your channel, you will have to take prior permission from roku team.  They will review you request and inform you accordingly whether you can use it in you channel. Although you can build custom component to handle epg, but it will not be an easy task. Organizations spends months to develop this type of components. Recently roku added some custom components(SGDEX). Although I didn't tried it yet, but I think its possible to implement epg grid using TimeGridView.

Comment: Yes this is also same thing, but its custom build component. They are not using roku's epg component.